# Como relacionar 2 tabelas json com php?

Tags: php, json, relacionamento

Boa tarde amigos. 
Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de planos onde preciso relacionar 2 tabelas json para filtrar os dados.

Porem não estou obtendo sucesso.
Tentei relaciona-las criando 2 foreachs e tentando criar um ponto de ligação entre as 2, porem não obtive sucesso.

Umas das minhas tabelas se chama planos.json e contem dados em array

Planos.json

```
    [
      {
        "codigo": 1,
        "minimo_vidas": 1,
        "faixa1": 10.00,
        "faixa2": 12,
        "faixa3": 15.00
      }
    ]
```

segunda tabela é a precos.json

```
    [
      {
        "registro": "reg1",
        "nome": "Bitix Customer Plano 1",
        "codigo": 1
      }
    ]
```

as duas a "chave estrangeira" codigo como referenciamento, porem não to conseguindo unir as duas e exibi-las.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar alguma solução ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso, sugiro usar `json_decode` e transforma-los em array, em seguida processar estes arrays pra realizar o 'relacionamento'. O ideal seria a API já estar te retornando estes dados relacionados dentro de uma propriedade num objeto json.

```
$planos = json_decode($jsonPlanos, true);
$precos = json_decode($jsonPrecos, true);

//indexar array planos:
$idxPlanos = [];
foreach ($planos as $p){
   $idxPlanos[$p['codigo']] = $p;
}

foreach ($precos as $p){
   $idxPlanos[$p['codigo']]['preco'] = $p; 
}

//liberar arrays
unset($precos); unset($planos);
//exibir array pronto
var_dump($idxPlanos);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, me ajudou pra caramba. Seu código funcionou perfeito, só tive que colocar um 'true' na linha $planos = json_decode($jsonPlanos, true); e também na de preços, e rodou liso demais. Mais uma vez obrigado. FORTE ABRAÇO